# Is there a possibility to refresh a certain frame in Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I would like to refresh a certain IFrame using Selenium.
Only approach that came to my mind was to use a Key for an f5 on certain WebElement.

```java
driver.switchTo().parentFrame();
driver.findElement(By.id("main")).sendKeys("\\uE035");
```

But it does reload entire page and this is not what i need.
There is and option to reload it using right mouse button on a chosen frame then you can pick "reload a frame" option but chrome does not provide shortcut for this one which makes it impossible to use SendKeys() on a certain WebElement.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're ivoking the refresh on the parentElement rather than the actual iFrame element.

Try something like below. If you have multiple iframe elements, you'll need to use a different selector.

```
        JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
        js.executeScript("document.getElementsByTagName('iframe')[0].contentWindow.location.reload();");
```